# How to price a credit-risky zero-coupon bond?

Tags: zero-coupon, default-risk

I recently received the following exercise:

> Construct a $n=10$-period binomial model for the short-rate, $r_{i,j}$.
>
> The lattice parameters are:
>
> - $r_{0,0}=5\%$,
> - $u=1.1$,
> - $d=0.9$ and;
> - $q=1−q=1/2$.

This I did do at this point without any problems.

> Assume that the 1-step hazard rate in node $(i,j)$ is given by $H_{i,j}=ab^{j-i/2}$ where $a=0.01$ and $b=1.01$. Compute the price of a zero-coupon bond with face value $F=100$ and recovery $R=20%$.

Now this is a novel part for me as I till now did not price zero-coupon bonds with a default risk.

My question from here is how do I, incorporate the values of the hazard lattice as well as the recovery rate into a zero-coupon bond pricing lattice. (Thus what formula would I use in order to do so correctly)?

Comment: Hi Noir, to get the best answers to your problem, you should format your question a bit differently. It's a good question, but at first glance, looks just like "how do I do this exercise from start to finish".

Comment: Hey AfterWorkGuinness thanks for the comment, I reworded the last part of the exercise a bit, as I am indeed only interested in the very last step of the exercise.

Comment: Your notation is super confusing, can you double check as I think you have errors in the problem statement for example " q=1−q=1/2" I assume you mean p = 1-q and q = 0.5 where p is probability of an up-jump and q is the probability of a down-jump ?

Comment: I know but it is the notation I was provided with, that is why I also posted the exercise in quotation marks. Yes you are correct its a 50/50 thing weather an up or down jump will occur.

Comment: You should make the notation clearer by not using single letter variables, this will make your question easier to understand and get you an answer faster.

Comment: Your credit-risk text book should have a formula. It's really the normal price - (prob of default * (portfolio - recovery rate)). My notation is informal (I don't have the book with me),  but it's really saying getting the probability of default and how much is lost once it defaults.